# How to use AddForce to make a gameobject jump. The following code is attached to a gameobject. Gameobject wont jump when mouse key pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerspeed * Time.deltaTime;
float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


//check if mouse button prsessed for jumping
        IsClicked = (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0));
       

        if ((IsClicked) && IsOnGround())
           rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        
        //move player
        transform.Translate(0,0, translation);
        transform.Rotate(0, rotation, 0);
    }
    //checks if berry is grounded

    bool IsOnGround()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distancetoground))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

The above code is attached to a gameobject. Gameobject won't jump when mouse key pressed. I think the problem is I can move the gameobject using translate. but unable to add a jumping force as required when the left mouse button is pressed as I have set the y axis paraemter in the translate. Don't know how to get round this one. Any offers?

Comment: You ask for force and then manually teleport the player to its next location

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use transform.translate and AddForce at the same time, because translate simply teleports an object to another location and ignores all physics.

Comment: Also, check if IsOnGround is working correctly (distance ground) and also make sure your object up axis is upward ( some times when you import an object from blender,... their axis aren't correct )

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a rigid body instead it might not be more efficient but it works fine for me. You add a force upwards when the button is pressed (This won't work in games where you move your platform instead of a player)

Comment: They did already ..

Comment: They did. `if ((IsClicked) && IsOnGround())
           rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).